# Access knockoutjs ViewModel from outside binding scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a page that has a parent area which has two children areas, simplified as following

```
<div id='parent'>
   ....other parent's html markups ....

   <div id='signin'>
        ... signin's html markups ....
   </div>
   <div id='register'>
        ... register's html markups ....
   </div>
</div>
```

Each of 'child' divs binds to their own viewmodel

```
ko.applyBindings(new SignInModel(), document.querySelector('#signin'))
ko.applyBindings(new RegisterModel(), document.querySelector('#register'))
```

1. How can I bind parent's html markups that are outside of both children divs with properties of either signin or register viewmodel ?? Or do I have to merge this two viewmodels to one, then bind it to parent?
2. How can I bind a html markup inside 'signin' div to a property of SignInModel viewmodel, or the otherway round?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not include the span in the `applyBindings` call?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi It is a simplified example, I will update it, the actual work I am doing basically has a parent area that has some markups and two children area (one is login, one for register), where each of children has their own viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You have to bind to the parent and then you can use your data-bind to the span.